# exporting app to access and update cookie not working

Tags: node.js, express

I have app.js page to that exports the app variable, and route to other page, from those pages I want access app variable for cookie variables.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//the rest code goes here

module.exports = app;
```

then on dao.js page

```
var app = require('../app');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
```

then the error is ***app.use is not a function***
what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I use this code and I don't see that error.
I think in :

```
//the rest code goes here
```

change your app variable.
Or are you sure that `../app` is your app.js in your post.